# problem with printing a variable to a binary file

Tags: c, binary

I can't add 5 to the file. I know that if you add 5 to the array, it will solve the problem. But I need no array.

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE* a = fopen("bin.bin", "wb");
    int b = 5;
    fwrite(b, sizeof(int), 1, a);
    fclose(a);
}
```

Comment: What array? What problem?

Comment: For future questions, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). In short: If you ask questions about build errors or warnings, then include the full and complete build output in the question itself, copy-pasted as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just ***guessing*** here, but I think you get a build error because the first argument to `fwrite` should be a pointer, but you provide an `int` value instead.

This is easily solved by using the address-of operator `&` to get a pointer to the variable `b`:

```
fwrite(&b, sizeof b, 1, a);
```